# Can use IEEE 754 format floating point in SVG file for precision

Tags: svg, floating-point, precision

SVG support use IEEE 754 32 bit float format for draw/save objects with high precision?

Example SVG file here use big endian IEEE float format for draw black circle with radius 100 at (50; 50), fill opacity 1.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg version="1.1"  width="100" height="100" >

<circle cx="#42480000" cy="#42480000" r="#42C80000" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="#3F800000" stroke="none" />

</svg>
```

Open file in Inkscape not show circle, outline mode also show nothing. I guess no support for IEEE float.

Reason want use this form, use hex float number not lose precision from convert decimal when write file, then convert back to hex when read file. Useful for use SVG replace PDF.

Comment: No, you can't write numbers that way in SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SVG does not allow you to specify numbers through a non-decimal representation.

The good news is, you don't have to. You just have to specify numbers with enough precision to uniquely identify the floating-point value you're referring to. How you do this will depend on your programming language and XML/SVG library, but there's no need to use a non-decimal representation if all you want is to exactly represent a particular floating-point value.